# How do I remove the last Hyphen

Tags: c#

This C# script generates a code but I need to remove the last hyphen

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int codeLenght = 16;
            for (int i = 0; i < codeLenght; i++)
            {
                GenerateALetter letter = new GenerateALetter();
                string code = new string(letter.GenerateRandomLetter());

                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                {
                    code += "-";
                }
                

                Console.Write(code);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class GenerateALetter
    {
        public string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        Random random = new Random();

        public string GenerateRandomLetter()
        {`your text`
            int index = random.Next(alphabet.Length);
            return alphabet[index].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

I tried string replace but it did not work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try substring from 0 to length - 1 having checked that the last character is a dash/hyphen.

Comment: FYI "did not work" is not a good problem description: what did you use, what did you see, what did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend) to remove any trailing dashes:

```
Console.Write(code.TrimEnd('-'));
```

or, *after* your loop:

```
code = code.TrimEnd('-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add - 1 in your for loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < codeLenght - 1; i++)
```